# Azure AD custom rule to add character to existing attribute

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I am migrating off ADFS to Azure AD and the vendor requires an M be added to the start of the employeeid attribute. In ADFS, I just wrote the custom rule Below:

`c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/employeeID"] => issue(Type = "wfu_id", Value = "M" + c.Value);`

What the claim then is, is M(and the employeeID) And it worked great. However, I can't figure out how to accomplish this in Azure AD. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried transformations but don't see the way.

Comment: can you use RegexReplace to capture the employeeid value and prepend 'M' to it via a transformation?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization#regex-based-claims-transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex transformation, and replace the beginning of the string `^` with your text to prepend `M`
[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I couldn't figure out the patterns.